# jquery's .css('visibility', 'hidden') method isn't hiding the element

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code

```
$(function() {

  $('#totalRecords').css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
  alert("hi");

 });
```

Problem is that it doesnt hide my drop down which is

```
   <span id="lblCodes" class="pol" style="top:4;left:209;">Codes</span>
  <span id="totalRecords" class="pol" style="top:4;left:350;visibility:visible;">
  <select id="startRecord" >
   <option value="0"></option>
  </select>
  </span>
```

Is there a method for parent() or something. I thought jquery would just select from id. I see alert("hi") prompt but the dropdown doesnt get hidden

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you not mean

```
  $('#startRecord').hide();
```

You seem to have the wrong id in your selector for the dropdown. Also, [visibility and display are quite different.](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13638) Unless you want the hidden dropdown to still occupy the space, you'll want to use `display` instead of `visibility`

Answer (score 1):

I would say you should use the "display" attribute and set it to "none" to hide an element.
So your code would be:

```
$('#totalRecord').css('display', 'none');
```

And it should be "totalRecord" instead of "totalRecords"

Answer (score 1):

remove "visibility:visible" from style attribute and use $('#startRecord').hide();

Answer (score 0):

I think you are choosing the wrong id for the selector. If you need to hide the dropdown, 
use
$('#startRecord').hide(); 
OR
$('#startRecord').css('display', 'none');
OR
$('#startRecord').css('visibility', 'hidden');

Note: visibility and display are different in their functionality.